# AngularJS dropdown select not working

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-ng-repeat, schema, mean-stack

I am using Angular to write a dropdown select menu with a few options that gets submitted to a database. In the front end html:

```
Role Type: 
<select ng-model = "Role_Type">
    <option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role}}"> {{role}} </option>
</select>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.roles = ['Teacher', 'Student', 'Janitor', 'Principal'];
$scope.addNewEntry = function() {
      entrys.addNewEntry({
         Role_Type: $scope.role,
      });
}
```

And in my backend (using Mongoose.js) schema, I have:

```
var EntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      Role_Type: String,
});
```

I am using the following code to display it back on the front end:

```
Role Type:
{{entry.Role_Type}}
```

But this does not work. Nothing is displayed back on the front end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-repeat`, try using `ng-options` which is meant for repeating values in a dropdown menu.

```
<select ng-model="Role_Type" ng-options="role for role in roles"></select>
```